# How to convert Cartopy tiles in grayscale?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, cartopy

I'm trying to display tiles downloaded via Cartopy's `img_tiles` module in gray scale. That's because I would like to overlay color-coded satellite data and I would prefer a background as little distracting as possible.

The various tiles providers as documented in the [source code](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/master/lib/cartopy/io/img_tiles.py) allow the use of a `desired_tile_form` during initialization. The documentation is not entirely clear about the possible values one could assign to that parameter (only "RGB" is mentioned), but digging a bit in the code I see that it is passed to `img.convert`, which is a PIL.image method.

Now the [PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#the-image-class) says:

> The current version supports all possible conversions between “L”,
>   “RGB” and “CMYK.” The matrix argument only supports “L” and “RGB”.
>
> When translating a color image to black and white (mode “L”), the
>   library uses the ITU-R 601-2 luma transform:
>   [...]

So it would appear that using the "L" mode would turn the image in black and white, however that doesn't really seem to work in my case.

Example:

Standard "RGB" mode:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt

figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
request = cimgt.StamenTerrain()
ax = plt.axes(projection=request.crs)
ax.set_extent([94, 102, 0, 6])
ax.add_image(request, 8)
plt.show()
```

[image: RGB mode]

(Not working) Black and white mode:

```
figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
request = cimgt.StamenTerrain(desired_tile_form="L")

ax = plt.axes(projection=request.crs)
ax.set_extent([94, 102, 0, 6])
ax.add_image(request, 8)
plt.show()
```

[image: bw not working]

I had similar results with `GoogleTiles()`.

What is the correct way to turn tiles to black and white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's by design, but it looks like the default colormap is being used here. You can pass a different colormap to the `add_image()` method, e.g:

```
ax.add_image(request, 8, cmap='gray')
```

[Here's a list of colormaps available in Matplotlib.](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)